# Syntax Error in a line of code looking at a specific cell in a sheet and looking for the word "Yes"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Syntax error. (line 23, file "Code")Dismiss error for:

```
if (sheet.getRange("Y2").getValue() == "Yes")) {
```

I've looked all over google and see examples using substring and some other more complicated things, but this seems like it should be simnple. I was able to do it with numbers, but this line is killing me. Maybe time to walk away from the code for a bit lol.

Please and thanks on any help. I feel like I am missing something small.

Comment: This line itself seems fine. You should probably give context around it - it might be something just before, if the previous line is not terminated correctly. But just to be safe, also add few lines after it.

Comment: This is a little before and a little after. I'm not seeing anything missing right before. Thoughts?  
  
  var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow() + 1;
  var CurrentDateString2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  
  
 if (sheet.getRange("Y2").getValue() == "Yes")) {
   
   
         MailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "Casper Truck Report ", "Casper Truck Report: ";
    Utilities.sleep(5000);    
   sheet.getRange("Y2").setValue("No");
    
  }
}

Comment: You have a second (unnecessary) closing paran `)` just prior to `{`

Comment: might have just been blind. it gives me another error, but I misrread the line. let me see if I can fix. thank you for replies. sometimes it's just an outside view

Comment: All good in the hood. Thank you. My brain wouldn't show me the line. Cheers!